# add-apt-repository behind a special proxy where URLs need to prefixed by the IP of the proxy

Tags: proxy, add-apt-repository

At work, our Linux servers are behind a proxy, therefore the urls need to look like this in order to be reachable from our servers, for example :

```bash
PROXY_IP=x.y.z.t
example URL : http://$PROXY_IP/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Trying to add the Launchpad PPA [ppa:rmescandon/yq](https://launchpad.net/%7Ermescandon/+archive/ubuntu/yq), so first I tried :

```bash
$ export http_proxy=http://x.y.z.t
$ sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:rmescandon/yq
```

That command hanged so I pressed CTRL+C.

Then I tried something else :

```bash
$ sudo add-apt-repository deb http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main
Repository: 'deb http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu jammy main'
Description:
Archive for codename: jammy components: main
More info: http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_x_y_z_t_ppa_launchpadcontent_net_rmescandon_yq_ubuntu-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_x_y_z_t_ppa_launchpadcontent_net_rmescandon_yq_ubuntu-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_x_y_z_t_ppa_launchpadcontent_net_rmescandon_yq_ubuntu-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_x_y_z_t_ppa_launchpadcontent_net_rmescandon_yq_ubuntu-jammy.list
Hit:1 http://x.y.z.t/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://x.y.z.t/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://x.y.z.t/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:4 http://x.y.z.t/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:5 http://x.y.z.t/apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease
Get:6 http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu jammy InRelease [18.0 kB]
Err:6 http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6657DBE0CC86BB64
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6657DBE0CC86BB64
E: The repository 'http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Finally, I created a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yq.list` file myself by replacing the `https://` by `http://x.y.z.t/` in the `deb https://` lines.

But, the `sudo apt update` failed with this error message :

```bash
W: GPG error: http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6657DBE0CC86BB64
E: The repository 'http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

EDIT0 : Checking this PPA is reachable from behind the proxy :

```bash
$ curl http://x.y.z.t/ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rmescandon/yq/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release -sc)/Release.gpg
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=q6JV
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

EDIT0 : After some investigation, I found out the proxy used was `apt-cacher-ng`.

I might have to add other PPAs, how can I do that easily ?

Comment: "At work our Linux servers are behind a proxy therefore ***the reachable urls*** would look like this", are you sure that this ppa repository is configured to be reachable through the proxy? The errors seem like, that Ubuntu has tried to install directly from the proxy server, not somewhere that the proxy has redirected.

Comment: @EmreTalha **_are you sure that this ppa repository is configured to be reachable through the proxy?**_

Hope my EDIT0 answers your question.